# Struggling with Nativescript Geolocation Plugin

Tags: geolocation, nativescript

When using the nativescript geolocation plugin in a semi rural area, the results are wildly inaccurate, sometimes as much as 500 meters away. The results always place me at the nearest urban development rather than in the field in which I am stood. This does not happen when I am in a fully urbanised ennvironment, where results are always perfect. The field in which I walk is the highest point in my area, with phone mast arrays aplenty, so I am unsure why these results occur.

To me, the results are somehow coming from screwed up phone signal triangulation and distant wifi signals. I have tried to eradicate this by de-activating my sim card to use GPS only, but then NOTHING is returned. This suggests that GPS is not working, and I am relying on wifi and phone signal data for positioning, but as I am trying to develop an app for use in areas of poor phone signal, GPS only positioning is vital (and, at around 20 meters accuracy in most cases - perfectly acceptable for my purposes).

```js
function buttonGetLocationTap(args) {


    var location = geolocation.getCurrentLocation({
        desiredAccuracy: accuracy.any,
        updateDistance: 0,
        maximumAge: 5000,
        timeout: 5000


     //   desiredAccuracy: 1
     //   , updateDistance: 10
     //   , minimumUpdateTime: 600000
     //   , maximumAge: 600000
     //   , timeout: 5000


    }).
    then(function(loc) {
        if (loc) {

            var match = 'n';
            var z = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < x.markers.length; i++) {
                var names = x.markers[i].name;
                var items = x.markers[i].coordinates;

                var targetLatitude = (items.latitude);
                var targetLongitude = (items.longitude);
                var currentLatitude = (loc.latitude.toFixed(4));
                var currentLongitude = (loc.longitude.toFixed(4));

                var targetLatitudelow=targetLatitude -0.0005;
                var targetLatitudehigh=targetLatitude +0.0005;
                var targetLongitudelow=targetLongitude -0.0005;
                var targetLongitudehigh=targetLongitude +0.0005;

                if (currentLatitude >= targetLatitudelow && currentLatitude <= targetLatitudehigh) {
                    if (currentLongitude >= targetLongitudelow && currentLongitude <= targetLongitudehigh) {
                        match = 'y';
                        z = JSON.stringify(names);
                        console.log(z);
                        page.bindingContext = {
                            username: z
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    match = 'n';
                    z = currentLatitude + currentLongitude;
                    console.log(z);
                    page.bindingContext = {
                        username: z
                    }



                }
                ;
                if (match =='y') { break; }
            }
        }
```

I would expect the same result in the semi rural area as the urbanised, am clearly have two problems:

1.Why is GPS only not working
2.Despite GPS not working - why are the results of wifi and phone signal data so wildly inaccurate when I am stood next to a mobile phone mast in the middle of a field??

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Did you try to cross verify your location in Google Maps app while using GPS? Sometimes it takes a while for GPS to detect your location.

Comment: Hi Manoj. Thanks for your interest and reply. I use JSON data (not included in the code above) with predefined points along what is my routine evening dog walk. I have verified those points via google maps thoroughly and added a degree of error ratio along the long and lat points which work perfectly for recognising I am at the points marked 'home' and 'field entrance', both of which are right next to urbanised points. Points marked 'View' and 'Barn' which are more rural return incorrect results. I have stood at these points for minutes on end to see if the results improve, but they don't : (

Answer (score 0):

Set desiredAccuracy to Accuracy.high

Your location deceleration would then become as follows:

```
    var location = geolocation.getCurrentLocation({
        desiredAccuracy: Accuracy.high,
        updateDistance: 0,
        maximumAge: 5000,
        timeout: 5000
    })
```